# Set custom domain for Azure Blob Storage in Resource Manager (new portal)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

I created an Azure Storage account using the Resource Manager model (the new portal), and now I'd like to configure a custom domain for blob storage. [The documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/) says to do this using the old portal (for Classic accounts), but my storage account doesn't show up there (because it's a Resource Manager account and not a Classic account). The new portal also doesn't provide a way for me to set the custom domain; it just points me to the storage page on the old portal.

Any idea how I can set a custom domain for blob storage?

Answer (score 2):

As of writing, the feature is not yet available in the preview portal for Azure Blob Storage in resource manager.

However, the corresponding setting is located under

Your Storage Account >> Services >> Blobs >> Settings >> Custom domains

If you want to do it using Azure PowerShell, here is the syntax

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -AccountName "mystorageaccount" -CustomDomainName "www.domainname.com" -UseSubDomain $True
```

Comment: I'm surprised to see this answer getting down voted.

Comment: The setting Emmanuel TOPE lists isn't actually available in the portal. As I mentioned in my original question, it just redirects you to the classic portal, which doesn't even show my storage account. But I'll certainly try Powershell and post an update when I'm done.

Comment: The setting is present please read it carefully. He said storage account and then click on "Blob" and then go to properties not the storage account properties.